# Adding button dynamically in table with angular 4

Tags: angular, frontend

Hi I am working on web application with angular 4 used as front end technology.
I need to create and display various tables depending on users options selection. There are 8 to 10 possible tables depends on what user selects.

I am doing it by creating the table headers/data dynamically in the component on user selection.

I just populate the leaveColums(Holding table  headers) and leaveData(Holding table data) and then render the same in html page.

```
switch (this.chartName) {
      case 'Employee': {
        if ('B' === this.selectedLabel) {
          this.leaveColums = this.employeeBalanceLeaveColumms;
          this.employeeService.getBalanceLeaves().subscribe(result => {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              let applyButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>';
              let row = [result[i].leaveType.leaveType, result[i].availableBalance , applyButton];
              this.leaveData.push(row);
            }
          });
        } else {

          this.leaveColums = this.employeeeLeaveColumms;
          this.employeeService.getLeaves(this.selectedLabel).subscribe(result => {


            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

              // Safari unable parse 2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+0000 format hence parse it
              let appliedOn = result[i].appliedOn.substring(0, result[i].appliedOn.length - 5);
              let leaveFrom = result[i].appliedOn.substring(0, result[i].leaveFrom.length - 5);
              let leaveTo = result[i].appliedOn.substring(0, result[i].leaveTo.length - 5);



              let row = [
                result[i].leaveType.leaveType,
                result[i].numberOfDays,
                this.pipe.transform(new Date(appliedOn), 'shortDate'),
                this.pipe.transform(new Date(leaveFrom), 'shortDate'),
                this.pipe.transform(new Date(leaveTo), 'shortDate'),
                result[i].leaveStatusId.statusDesc,
                result[i].leaveReason
              ];

             this.leaveData.push(row);

            }
          });
        }
      }
```

my html page is

```
<div>
    <table class="table-bordered table-striped">
        <th>{{chartName}}  {{selectedLabel}}</th>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of leaveColums">{{column}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of leaveData">
            <td *ngFor="let data of row">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

But the issue is when I tried to add button in any column it not getting printed the as string instead of rendering button. It might due to angular converting < or > chars into unicode i.e. (> of <).

How to resolve this I don't want to add multiple if else in html page as I already wrote if else into component.ts to populate the data.

Comment: Share the code where you tried add buttons

Comment: Its already there



let applyButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>';
              let row = [result[i].leaveType.leaveType, result[i].availableBalance , applyButton];

Comment: In this code, you are creating an object with 3 properties only. But in the render code you are applying a pipe convertStringToHtml which does the actual rendering. Please provide the pipe code where you add the button to the actual view

Comment: Use Renderer2 https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 to create new elements or to asing a event to element created "by code". (Really I think is better you re-think your code to create the buttons in a "more angular way")